# Islam on Blue Evil Eye bracelets

Tags: evil-eye

There is no doubt Islam has mentioned, evil eyes. But there are some bracelets and lockets containing evil eyes. I asked one of my Turkish friends, why do they wear that, she said - "It attracts the attention of the god(??) of evil eye and the evil eye bad luck escapes"(??!)

Can anyone refer something regarding this, based on Islam?

Comment: This is superstition.

Comment: It is superstitious but somehow popular in Islamic culture so it is interesting where it comes from and what Islamic scholars said about it +1